# How to Uninstall Bitdefender from Mac Book

Tags: macbook, bitdefender

I want remove Bitdefender Internet Security 2017 (BD) from my Macbook Pro (running el capitan) due to its processes hogging up my CPU and thrashing my disk to the ground - but despite my efforts for the past hour I am still unable to find out how to UNINSTALL this app from my Mac !

1. I have tried (after searching www for instrution) to remove the it from ~/Library/Application Support - but cannot find any BD folder under that location
2. I have tried to contact their support but kept on getting into a loop - it looks as though the company is making the customer jump through hoops just to tire them out :

   - (A) I went on https://www.bitdefender.com/support/consumer/
   - (B) Entered my product name & nature of issue
   - (C) Selected Directly contact our Support Team (an icon with an email image)
   - (D) It redirected me back to step (A) above !

I selected the Chat with support (an icon with a speech bubble) - but still gets redirected to step (A) again.

I have purchased multiple licenses of Bitdefender Internet Security for my Windows & Mac devices and just looking for very basic support - and still cannot get into with them via email nor chat !

Anyone know how to uninstall this AV off a macbook - please help !

Answer (score 0):

Applications > Utilities > BitdefenderUninstaller [alias].

The original isn't in `/Library/Application Support`, it's in `/Library/Bitdefender`